# why i dont see update files website on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have updated the static website files on AWS S3 - but I don't see the changes when I refresh the page in the browser. Please help

I have tried everything, but I don't know what I can do

Answer (score 2):

Maybe cache works somewhere. please try

1. delete your browser cache
2. use another browser never accessed your file
3. refreash your cloudfront cache, if have
4. add a new file(not update old ones), and try access it
5. delete a file which you can access, and wait to see what happens